# How can I get my CSS hover effect to cover the entire top and bottom of my navigation bar?

Tags: html, css

I would like it so that when you hover over each link, the hover effect covers both top and bottom of the navigation bar, as well as a little padding to the left and right. How can I achieve this? Thank you.

For example: [image: Example]

```
#navigation {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 65px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.58);
    opacity: 0.9;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: 20px;
    top: 10px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#navigation > ul {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#navigation > ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px 20px;
}

#navigation > ul > li > a {
    color: #fff;
    font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

#navigation > ul > li > a:hover, #navigation > ul > li > a:active {
    color: #FFF;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rxejwqL2/

Comment: Is javascript an option for you? If yes, onmouseover and onmouseout are your friends here. Let me know so that I can post an answer.

Comment: Yes, I can use JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved easily with "the right" CSS.

All you need to do is to give paddings to the right elements, in this case the <a></a> tags.

I have stripped your css to only include what's required to get the desired effect. You can add more stuff to it to get rounded corners etc.

Try this:

```css
#navigation {
    width: 1000px;
    background-color: #444444;
}
#navigation > ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
}
#navigation > ul > li > a {
    color: #fff;
    font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 20px;
    height: 100%;
}
#navigation > ul > li > a:hover, #navigation > ul > li > a:active {
    background-color: #666666;
}
```

```html
<div id="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="/">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things going on:

- default browser styles
- padding on li while hover on a tag

I think the following will get you what you are looking for. It seems to preserve your corners in chrome and firefox.

```
#navigation {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 65px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.58);
    opacity: 0.9;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: 20px;
    top: 10px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#navigation > ul {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#navigation > ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 16px 20px;
}
#navigation > ul > li > a {
    color: #fff;
    font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#navigation > ul > li:hover, #navigation > ul > li:active {
    color: #FFF;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the ul tag and li tag 100% height of your div #navigation tag by doing the following - `height:100%; margin:0; to #navigation > ul` , then `line-height: 65px;` to `#navigation > li` , and change your hover to the li only with

```
#navigation > ul > li:hover {
    color: #FFF;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}
```

So the whole css would be as follows -

```
#navigation {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 65px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.58);
    opacity: 0.9;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: 20px;
    top: 10px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#navigation > ul {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    list-style-type: none;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
#navigation > ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px 20px;
    line-height: 65px;
}
#navigation > ul > li > a {
    color: #fff;
    font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}
#navigation > ul > li:hover {
    color: #FFF;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}
```

This will give you the full height of the div plus the padding you added.
http://jsfiddle.net/rxejwqL2/4/

Answer (score 0):

Follow the following example and it will work

```
<i><HTML>
<head>
<link href="layouts.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="menu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"    />
<title>LOGIN</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="Holder">
<div id="Header"> </div>
<div id="NavBar">
<nav>
<ul>
       <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Register</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Forgot Password</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>
<div id="Content">
< div id="PageHeading">
 <h1>PAGE HEADING </h1>
</div>
<div id="ContentLeft">
<h2>Your Message Here</h2>
 <h6><br/>
  <br/>
YOUR MESSAGE 
</h6>
</div>
<div id="ContentRight"></div>
</div>
<div id="Footer"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html></i>
```

CSS

```
 nav ul{

 margin:0;

 padding:0;

}

nav ul li{

list-style-type:none;

float:left;

display:block;

   width:150px;

height:60px;

text-align:center;

line-height:55px;

font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;

font-size:17px;

}
nav ul li a{

text-decoration:none;

color:#FFFFFF;

}
nav ul li:hover{

background-color:rgb(242,242,242); 
}

nav ul li:hover a{

display:block;

color:#000;
}
```